# Finding the relevant records using XQuery/XPath

Tags: sql, xpath, xquery

I'm very very new to XQUERY/XPATH :) so I could very well be going about this the wrong way. I have a customer object serialized and stored in a database column in the following format.

```
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Addresses>
<AddressBlock>
  <AddressLine1>1234 SomeStreet Ave.</AddressLine1>
  <City>SomeCity</City>
  <State>SomeState</State>
  <Zipcode>SomeZip</Zipcode>
</AddressBlock>
<AddressBlock>
  <AddressLine1>5678 SomeOtherStreet Ave.</AddressLine1>
  <City>SomeOtherCity</City>
  <State>SomeOtherState</State>
  <Zipcode>SomeOtherZip</Zipcode>
</AddressBlock>
</Addresses>
</Customer>
```

I'm looking for a way to select this record if addressline1 and city in the same addressblock contains certain keywords. I have the following statement that almost does what I'm looking for.

```
select * 
from users 
where [UserData].exist('/Customer/Addresses/AddressBlock/AddressLine1/text()[contains(upper-case(.),""SOMESTREET"")]')=1
and [UserData].exist('/Customer/Addresses/AddressBlock/City/text()[contains(upper-case(.),""SOMECITY"")]')=1"
```

My only problem is this statment will also return the record if the first addressblock contains the addressline1 and the second addressblock contains the city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test both conditions in the same XQuery.

```
select * 
from users 
where [UserData].exist('/Customer/Addresses/AddressBlock
                         [contains(upper-case(AddressLine1[1]),"SOMESTREET") and 
                          contains(upper-case(City[1]),"SOMECITY")]')=1
```